# Opencv-python detect yellow highlighted text contour from page image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, highlight, contour

I'm trying to detect (and then do ocr) on ONLY the physically yellow-highlighted text from the image of a page. I want to essentially digitize my highlights in a physical book to store them. I'm using opencv python and have tried some basic contour detection and thresholds with no luck...

I think once I can get the contour of the highlighter, I can crop that portion of the image and then do OCR? But not sure how to extract the contour

Comment: You need to add some sample images along with sample code you have written to solve this problem.

Comment: here is an idea for your problem http://ciphervision.com/Color-based-object-detection

Comment: @flamelite Thanks, this helped! I still need to manually make sure of the hue boundaries but it's doable